# Webphere 9 :Runtime JSP compilation error getting into infinite logging and server hung

Tags: jsp, logging, java-8, websphere, websphere-9

We have moved from Websphere 8.5 to 9 with Java 8 recently which is giving us a hard time to find the reason of infinite logs accumulation when a JSP fails to compile(which was working perfect in 8.5) and in a few minutes, the server will stop responding.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any additional information you can offer? What is the compilation error you're seeing for the JSP? What is within the logs that is accumulating infinitely?

Comment: Sometime it relates to the struts tags, sometime it is something different.  When I use the precompileJSP option, Websphere had complains about translation issues with a few JSPs. But I am wondering, when it runs at run-time and it fails, why Websphere getting into infinite loop with logging. I am sorry if that doesn't help you much. I can put some logs here, but I don't think it will really help you much.